# How did they film two satellites colliding in supposed 'zero gravity' out in space?

Tags: film-techniques, gravity

The movie *Gravity* (2013) shows a woman that has been stranded out in space, she was rescued by a male friend that in fact died from lack of oxygen.

In the following clip:

The explorer is hit by debris.

*This is yet another scene*.

How do they film such things when there is supposedly *zero gravity*?

I do believe the actors are on ropes that lift them, but what about everything else like the debris that was floating around, especially the little bits and pieces?

Comment: She's not 'rescued by a male friend that had infact died from lack of oxygen'.  She rescues herself ... that entire scene is her hallucinating Kowalski.

Comment: Are you seriously asking if this was shot in space?  You know this is fiction right?  There is a thing called special effects.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Why would I think this movie was filmed in space? That would be insane to even think that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apart from the actors (who, as you say, are on wires in front of a green screen, or possibly even riding the [vomit comet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced-gravity_aircraft) for that authentic low-gravity look), almost the entirety of these two scenes would have been computer generated and layered in.

This video shows the various layers of CG rendering were put together to produce the spectacle. Even the suits are generated.